# WPF property trigger with enumeration

Tags: c#, wpf

I have WPF C# application with a user control I would like to animate between 3 states.

The user control:

```
    public partial class Cart : UserControl
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The <see cref="Layout" /> dependency property's name.
    /// </summary>
    public const string LayoutPropertyName = "Layout";

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the value of the <see cref="Layout" />
    /// property. This is a dependency property.
    /// </summary>
    public Visibility Layout
    {
        get
        {
            return (Visibility)GetValue(LayoutProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(LayoutProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty LayoutProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        LayoutPropertyName,
        typeof(Visibility),
        typeof(Carrito),
        new PropertyMetadata(Visibility.Hidden));
}
```

Also, I have a Styles.xaml where I define 3 storyboards I plan to reuse with property triggers to position the control in different positions.

```
    <Storyboard x:Key="CartVisible">
    <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" Duration="0:0:0.5" To="0,648,0,0" />
</Storyboard>
<Storyboard x:Key="CartCollapsed">
    <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" Duration="0:0:0.5" To="0,736,0,0" />
</Storyboard>
<Storyboard x:Key="CartHidden">
    <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" Duration="0:0:0.5" To="0,768,0,0" />
</Storyboard>
<Style TargetType="c:Cart" TargetType="FrameworkElement">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,768,0,0" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Layout" Value="Visible">
            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource CartVisible}" />
            </Trigger.EnterActions>
            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource CartHidden}" />
            </Trigger.ExitActions>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="Layout" Value="Collapsed">
            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource CartCollapsed}" />
            </Trigger.EnterActions>
            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource CartVisible}" />
            </Trigger.ExitActions>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="Layout" Value="Hidden">
            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource CartHidden}" />
            </Trigger.EnterActions>
            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource CartVisible}" />
            </Trigger.ExitActions>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Then, I have a xaml binding to the property Layout, which triggers the property value changes.

The issue is that the animation is not always working for each state change. All the examples I've seen are for bool properties using the Enter and ExitActions, but here I have 3 which may vary.

Is there a good way to make this work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've been able to fix it with the solution for [Animation not working correctly with data triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105171/animation-not-working-correctly-with-data-triggers)

The idea is to define the Storyboard in the EnterActions, and *before* the BeginStoryboard, make sure every other Storyboards are removed.

The fixed code is this: (Please note the s:S.Cart... which are constants held in a another class).

```
<Style TargetType="c:Cart">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="{x:Static s:S+Cart.Hidden}" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Layout" Value="Visible">
            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="CartCollapsed" />
                <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="CartHidden" />
                <BeginStoryboard Name="CartVisible">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin"
                                    Duration="0:0:0.5"
                                    To="{x:Static s:S+Cart.Visible}" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.EnterActions>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="Layout" Value="Collapsed">
            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="CartVisible" />
                <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="CartHidden" />
                <BeginStoryboard Name="CartCollapsed">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin"
                                    Duration="0:0:0.5"
                                    To="{x:Static s:S+Cart.Collapsed}" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.EnterActions>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="Layout" Value="Hidden">
            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="CartVisible" />
                <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="CartCollapsed" />
                <BeginStoryboard Name="CartHidden">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin"
                                    Duration="0:0:0.5"
                                    To="{x:Static s:S+Cart.Hidden}" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.EnterActions>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
```